# cannot absolute position when i insert position absolute in tag html

Tags: html, css, css-position

when i insert position absolute on my div, but the position cannot absolute.

```html
<div style="position: absolute;">
  <a class="bg-yellow fg-black bd-amber" style="padding: 5px; font-size: 12px; border-style: solid; border-width: 2px;" ng-show="alert">
    alert
  </a>
</div>
```

I wanted when in sliding , the content follow

Comment: You mean you want the div to keep its position when you scroll the page? That's `position: fixed`, not `absolute`.

Comment: no! i mean when scroll the page and then content follow it

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. How is "scroll the page and then content follow it" different from "keep its position when you scroll the page"?

Comment: Please be more elaborate in what yo uactually want to achieve. This is so brief it's hard to grasp at best in what you try to do.

Comment: yeah i mean the content keep its position when i scrool the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the div is position absolute you need to give property and value:

you can see the example given below:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_absolute

and also you want to slide you need to take position:fixed

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position&preval=fixed